# Limitações em uma consulta SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Tenho que fazer um relatório que mostre os principais clientes de cada vendedor (os 10 clientes que mais gastaram com cada vendedor)

Estou usado a base de dados da Oracle para fazer essa consulta.

Cada vendedor tem mais de 40 clientes, preciso limitar 10 clientes para todos os vendedores.

O select que estou usando:

```
 SELECT * FROM (   SELECT FILIAL, vendedor, CODV, cliente,SUM(valor), PERIODO fROM (SELECT ITPED.CODFIL FILIAL,
            ITPED.CODVENDR CODV,
            MAX(VEND.NOME) vendedor,
            cliente.nomcli cliente,
            SUM(ITPED.VLTOTITEM) VALOR,
            TO_CHAR(ITPED.DTPEDIDO, 'mm/yyyy') PERIODO
       FROM MOV_ITPED  ITPED,
            CAD_ITPROD ITPROD,
            VEN_VEND   VEND,
            cad_cliente cliente
      WHERE ITPROD.CODITPROD = ITPED.CODITPROD AND
            ITPED.CODVENDR = VEND.CODVENDR AND
            ITPED.CODFIL = VEND.CODFIL AND
            itped.codcli = cliente.codcli AND
            ITPED.DTPEDIDO BETWEEN '01/03/2019' AND '18/04/2019' AND
            ITPED.CODFIL = 3 AND ITPED.STATUS <> 9
      GROUP BY ITPED.CODFIL,
               ITPED.CODVENDR,
               ITPED.DTPEDIDO,
               cliente.nomcli

     UNION ALL

     SELECT ITSAIDA.CODFIL FILIAL,
            ITSAIDA.CODVENDR CODV,
            MAX(VEND.NOME) vendedor,
            cliente.nomcli cliente,
            SUM(ITSAIDA.VLTOTITEM) VALOR,
            TO_CHAR(ITSAIDA.DTNOTA, 'mm/yyyy') PERIODO
       FROM MOV_ITSAIDA ITSAIDA,
            CAD_ITPROD  ITPROD,
            VEN_VEND    VEND,
            cad_cliente cliente
      WHERE ITPROD.CODITPROD = ITSAIDA.CODITPROD AND
            ITSAIDA.CODVENDR = VEND.CODVENDR AND
            ITSAIDA.CODFIL = VEND.CODFIL AND
            ITSAIDA.codcli = cliente.codcli AND
            ITSAIDA.DTNOTA BETWEEN '01/03/2019' AND '18/04/2019' AND
            ITSAIDA.CODFIL = 3 AND ITSAIDA.STATUS <> 9
      GROUP BY ITSAIDA.CODFIL,
               ITSAIDA.CODVENDR,
               cliente.nomcli,
               ITSAIDA.DTNOTA)  GROUP BY FILIAL, vendedor, CODV, cliente, PERIODO ORDER BY 3 ASC, 5 DESC ) WHERE ROWNUM <= 10
```

Estava pensando se seria possível fazer um Loop passando os codigos dos vendedores, pois consegui limitar a quantidade de linha que o select retorna.

Comment: O que essa consulta te retorna e o que você deseja que ela retorne?

Comment: Ela retorna retorna a filial do vendedor, o nome do vendedor e todos clientes que fizeram compras com ele, e o mês que foi feita a compra. Porem tem vendedor que fez compras para mais de 40, precisaria pegar tipo os 10 clientes que mais gastaram para cada vendedor.

Comment: A cláusula ROWNUM <= 10 não atende?

Comment: Na verdade não, usei ela para tentar limitar a quantidade de cliente mas ela limita o select inteiro, no caso só ira aparecer o primeiro vendedor e os seus clientes, mas o segundo vendedor não aparece.

Comment: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/analytic-functions http://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-analytic-functions/oracle-rank/ use funções analiticas , exemplos a rodo deste top n por alguma quebra , RANK , DENSE_RANK etc